# Flex and Bison Calculator if issues

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to make my calculator give an answer of "INF" if someone tries to divide by 0, but the if statement won't work. op == '/' and b == 0 both work on their own, but not together with &&. Instead it makes the exe stop working.

Flex file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
extern  FILE* yyin;
        FILE* FileOutput;
#define YYSTYPE int
%}

%%

[0-9]+  { yylval = (int)strtol(yytext, NULL, 10); return INTEGER; }
"+" return ADD;
"-" return SUBTRACT;
"*" return MULTIPLY;
"/" return DIVIDE;
[ \t]  ;
.       yyerror();

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
FileOutput = fopen("output.c", "w");
yyparse();
fclose(FileOutput);
return 0;
}

int yywrap(void)
{
 return 1;
}

int yyerror(void)
{
 //printf("Error\n");
}
```

Bison file:

```
%{
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 extern FILE* FileOutput;
 #define YYSTYPE int

 void createcode(int result, int a, unsigned char op, int b);

%}



%token INTEGER
%token ADD SUBTRACT MULTIPLY DIVIDE

%left ADD SUBTRACT
%left MULTIPLY DIVIDE


%%
program: 
    | program statement
    ;

statement:
    expression '\n'     { printf("%d\n", $1); }
    | error '\n'            { yyerrok; }
    ;

expression: 
    INTEGER         { $$ = $1; }
    | expression ADD expression     { $$ = $1 + $3, createcode($$, $1, '+', $3);}
    | expression SUBTRACT expression        { $$ = $1 - $3; createcode($$, $1, '-', $3);}
    | expression MULTIPLY expression        { $$ = $1 * $3; createcode($$, $1, '*', $3);}
    | expression DIVIDE expression      { $$ = $1 / $3; createcode($$, $1, '/', $3);}
    | '(' expression ')'            { $$ = $2; }
    ;

%%

void createcode(int result, int a, unsigned char op, int b)
{
if (op == '/' && b == 0)
    printf("INF");
else
    printf("%d %c %d = %d\n", a, op, b, result);
}
```

Comment: The "exe stops working" because of `$$ = $1 / $3`, which is a divide-by-zero. That happens before createcode is even called.

Comment: I think you want to move the calculations to `createcode`.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, the division by 0 crashes the program. If you really want to do what you explained in the question, I would replace `$$ = $1/$3` by something like `$$ = ($3 == 0) ? 0 : $1/$3`. But it is not satisfying because with `int` you have no special value (line `NaN` for `float`) to indicate a wrong result.

However I think that this is not a good thing and that you should let the program crashes. Mathematically speaking dividing by 0 does not give infinity, it is genuinely undefined because it flips from -infinity to +infinity when you cross 0.